# Let $\tau,\phi:A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be faithful states on a C*-algebra A, with $\tau \geqslant \phi$. How do the GNS representations compare?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\tau,\phi:A \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be faithful states on a C* algebra A, with $\tau \geqslant \phi$.

Write $H_{\tau}, H_{\phi}$ for the GNS representation with respect to $\tau,\phi$ respectively, i.e. $H_{\tau}$ is the completion of $A$ with respect to the inner product $(a,b) \mapsto \tau(b^{*}a)$, and similarly for $H_{\phi}$.

The condition $\tau \geqslant \phi$ implies that the identity on $A$ extends to a map $p: H_{\tau} \rightarrow H_{\phi}$.

> Is the map $p$ injective or surjective? If it is not surjective, are there any conditions that guarantee that it is? When is $pp^{*} = 1$?

Left multiplication in $A$ extends to a representation of $A$ on both $H_{\tau}$ and $H_{\phi}$. Write $A_{\tau}$ and $A_{\phi}$ for the image of $A$ in $B(H_{\tau})$ and $B(H_{\phi})$ respectively.
Write $A_{\tau}''$, and $A_{\phi}''$ for the von Neumann completions of $A_{\tau}$ and $A_{\phi}$ respectively.

> Is it true that the map $\hat{p}:B(H_{\tau}) \rightarrow B(H_{\phi}), x \mapsto pxp^{*}$ restricts to a surjective homomorphism $A_{\tau}'' \rightarrow A_{\phi}''$?

---

Here are some things that I've tried so far:

Let's suppose that $pp^{*} = 1$. This implies that $\hat{p}$ is a homomorphism.

Moreover, in this case $\hat{p}$ restricts to a homomorphism $A_{\tau}'' \rightarrow A_{\phi}''$:

For all $a \in A$, and all $v \in A \subset H_{\tau}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
 p(av) = av = ap(v),
\end{equation*}
which then implies that the relation $p(av) = ap(v)$ holds for all $a \in A$ and all $v \in H_{\tau}$.
This means that the map $\hat{p}$ restricts to the identity on $A$, which thus extends to a homomorphism $\hat{p}: A_{\tau}'' \rightarrow A_{\phi}''$.

Clearly, the map $B(H_{\phi}) \rightarrow B(H_{\tau}), x \mapsto p^{*}xp$ is a right inverse to $\hat{p}$.
Does this map restrict to an algebra homomorphism $A_{\phi}'' \rightarrow A_{\tau}''$?

A sufficient condition is $p^{*}p \in A_{\tau}''$. In that case we can proceed as follows:
Suppose that $a \in A_{\phi}$, and $x \in A_{\tau}'$ and $v \in H_{\tau}$ then we compute
\begin{align*}
 p^{*}apxv = p^{*}paxv = p^{*}pxav = xp^{*}pav = xp^{*}apv,
\end{align*}
whence $p^{*}apx = xp^{*}ap$, and hence $p^{*}ap \in A_{\tau}''$.

Comment: What is meant by $\tau\ge\phi$? They map to $\mathbb C$. And what is GNS?

Comment: Because $\tau$ and $\phi$ are states, they map the positive elements of $A$ into $\mathbb{R}^{+}$. The statement $\tau \geqslant \phi$ then means that for all positive elements $a$ of $A$ we have $\tau(a) \geqslant \phi(a)$.

GNS stands for Gelfand-Naimark-Segal. It associates to every (faithful) state on $A$ a (faithful) representation of $A$ on a Hilbert space, essentially as in my question.

Comment: Alright. Thank you.

Comment: Very late comment, but: Assume that $\phi(x)<\tau(x)$ for some $x\geq 0$. Otherwise replacing $x$ by $x/\|x\|$, we may assume that $0\leq x\leq 1$. Thus $\phi(1-x)\leq \tau(1-x)$ and therefore $\phi(1)=\phi(x)+\phi(1-x)<\tau(x)+\tau(1-x)=\tau(1)$. In other words, if $\phi$ and $\tau$ are states, the relation $\phi\leq \tau$ already implies $\phi=\tau$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a general answer, but here are some ideas. Given a state $\tau$, let $h\in Z(A)_+$ with $\|h\|=1$, and define $\phi(a)=\tau(ha)$; then $\phi$ is a state with $\phi\leq\tau$.

You can check that in this case $p^*=p^*p=pp^*=M_h$ (multiplication by $h$). So $p$ is injective/surjective if and only if $h$, and you can construct examples with all three possible situations.

For  $\hat p:x\longmapsto pxp^*$ to be a homomorphism you need, in particular, that $pxp^*px^*p^*=pxx^*p^*$ for all $x\in A_\tau''$. This equality is 
$$
px(I-p^*p)x^*p=0,
$$
so $(I-p^*p)xp=0$ for all $x\in A_\tau''$. As the range of $p$ is dense, you get $(I-p^*p)x=0$. And by using $x\in A$ you obtain that $I-p^*p=0$. So $\hat p$ is a homomorphism if and only if $p^*p=I$.

Comment: That's really useful! Suppose that $p^{*}p = I$. Then we have, for all $v, w \in H_{\tau}$, the identity $\langle pv, pw \rangle_{\phi} = \langle v,w \rangle_{\tau}$. Now choosing $v,w \in A$, we have that $pv = v$ and $pw = w$ this implies that $\langle v,w \rangle_{\tau} = \langle v, w \rangle_{\phi}$ and hence that $H_{\tau} = H_{\phi}$. So $\hat{p}$ is a homomorphism if and only if $H_{\tau} = H_{\phi}$, and $p = I$. That's really surprising to me!